# Can I import songs I downloaded into garageband on my iPad, with no laptop fileshare?

Tags: ipad, garageband, import

Im a rapper, so all I want to do is import a beat onto garageband and record my vocals over that. Problem is I don't have a laptop, just the iPad. I have downloaded instrumetals on other apps. Is it possible to import these files into garageband just using the iPad(as this is all I have at my disposal)?

Comment: Which other apps?

Answer (score 1):

I created a:

Garageband Mac to iPad Oneshot Converter at the fixed1t blog.

http://fixed1t-music-software.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/mac-garageband-to-ipad-one-shot.html

it has links to free trial software, youtube video and an ebay purchase £5.